# how to give padding to the RichTextBox control in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, padding

I am developing windows application in vb.net. In that i have a RichTextBox Control in one of the form. Now i want some padding in the richtextbox. So my text will be start after some space (padding) like word document.

[image: Text start from inner square.]

So Can any one give some idea how to give padding to the RichTextBox control?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in property to allow for padding.  You could create your own control and handle the painting yourself (or find someone else who has - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21437/A-Padded-Rich-Text-Box-Subclass); but you might be able to easily achieve the look you want by docking the RichTextBox inside of a Panel.

Panel does have a `Padding` property.

If you use the same BackColor it might give the desired affect.  Scroll bars might look 'off' though; if you need it to scroll things will get more complicated - I think you'd be able to use a VScrollBar - with the same height as the Panel but managing the scrolling will get complicated.  You'd want to stop the RichTextBox from showing it's scroll bar; but you'll need to manage the scrolling with the VScrollBar.

If there aren't any better solutions offered up; I'll give this a try tonight and see if I can get it working :)

Comment: Thanks @Rob for your quick reply. i did in my code what you said. but when there is scrollbar in the richtextbox then it will come in side the panel in the richtextbox control. that i dont want. i want scrollbar in panel only. if user done up and down in that scrollbar then scroll will do in richtextbox.

Comment: i also check the code project code. in that i have one question that how to increase padding? means i want more padding then from where i can set it?

Comment: Ohh thanks @Rob. I tried all the ways to do this. but i cant. i am realy given up for the issue. and my requirement is very important. so i dont know what to do...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and this worked for me and least for the left margin.  Basically I selected all of the text and set the indent.

```
With RTB        'This changes the left margin for the whole thing
  Dim OldSelStart As Integer = .SelectionStart
  Dim OldSelLen As Integer = .SelectionLength
  .SelectionStart = 0
  .SelectionLength = Len(.Text)
  .SelectionIndent = 10
  .SelectionStart = OldSelStart
  .SelectionLength = OldSelLen
End With
```